# VSDBCMD vs. SQLCMD

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio-2010, project, datadude

Which is a better option for deploying databases VSDBCMD or SQLCMD when using a database project (VS 2010). Is there any major drawback other than the defaulted variables (databasename, datapath and logpath)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[vsdbcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) is a diff tool: it can analyze the .dbschema, compare it with the target db and bring the target db up to the schema in the .dbschema file by selectively adding, dropping and altering existing objects. [sqlcmd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) is only an execution tool, it takes a .sql script and blindly runs it. So it really apples to oranges, the two tools are quite different in purpose and capabilities.

Comment: For deployment purposes i.e. running the script - which one is preferable if i am not using the .dbschema and using the deployment file that is generated (.sql)?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, so it isn't easy to give you a good answer, but according to your comment to Remus's answer, I assume you are trying to execute the .sql script that vsdbcmd.exe generated. If my assumption is correct, you need to use sqlcmd.exe to execute this script.

According to [this thread on MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstsdb/thread/0ae888d1-d80e-49e0-b0c8-1e655c994488), the VSDB team didn't want to duplicate functionality in vsdbcmd.exe that already exists in sqlcmd.exe.

Comment: I should add that the thread I linked to is starting to get old (from sep. 2008), so things might have changed since then.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I was trying to use VSDBCMD with various options and it just seemed easier to use VSDBCMD to generate the deployable file and then use SQLCMD on different environments for the deployment. Thanks for the msdn link.

Comment: The danger here is that not all of the target databases may be the same and thus they need different scripts applying to them to bring them up to the target schema.  If all of your environments are guaranteed to be at the same schema all the time then doing the diff and then rolling out the results is ok, but still dangerous.